# Need help to install galileo

Tags: uninstall

I tried to install galileo in order to sync my Fitbit with Ubuntu 12.04.
Installation resulted in errors and I tried to uninstall it. Now I'm stuck and can't neither uninstall nor install. I encounter this error when trying to uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get remove galileo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
galileo
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 205 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 321770 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing galileo ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/galileo not found.
dpkg: error processing galileo (--remove):
subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/galileo not found.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
galileo
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Could someone please help me uninstall or install galileo properly?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the init script isn't there (perhaps it's a poorly packaged software) but you see what the error is here:

```
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/galileo not found.
```

Try tricking the install scripts by creating the missing file (empty), making it executable and attempting removal again:

```
sudo touch /etc/init.d/galileo
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/galileo
sudo apt-get remove galileo
```

Most packages apart from installing binaries, documentation, configuration files and others, also have instructions on what to do before/after the installation/removal and they're usually shell scripts which you can find here:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/packagename.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/packagename.prerm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/packagename.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/packagename.postinst
```

If you get such errors because the package maintainer either didn't do a very good job or you forced the installation on an unsupported distribution, you usually know:

- the package name
- the stage of the package life (postrm, prerm, preinst, postinst)

so you can look at the appropriate file and either remove or comment out the command that makes the process fail as it does here. Either this, or trick it as I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... I noticed in the error log this line:
/etc/init.d/galileo not found.
I created this file and after that I was able to uninsall and then correctly install it.
Sorry for confusion ..